# GeckoView Android Pixel 2 Errors

Tags: android, geckoview

I integrated GeckoView version 70.0.20190712095934 nightly into a sample app. It works totally fine (-> website shows up) on my old Nexus 5 with Android 6. But if I run the same app on my Pixel 2, the page doesn't load at all. I already tried using the latest stable GeckoView versions, which all work fine on the Nexus, but crash on the Pixel 2. With the latest version, I even got a SIGSEV error and complete crash on Pixel 2.

This is the logcat:

```
2019-11-08 12:50:30.262 14939-14982/? W/GeckoLinker: /data/app/com.geckoengine.example-790VO6zYdwJy299N7lcXcA==/lib/arm64/libnss3.so: unhandled flags #8 not handled
2019-11-08 12:50:30.264 14939-14982/? W/GeckoLinker: /data/app/com.geckoengine.example-790VO6zYdwJy299N7lcXcA==/lib/arm64/libxul.so: unhandled flags #8 not handled
2019-11-08 12:50:30.264 14939-14982/? W/GeckoLinker: /data/app/com.geckoengine.example-790VO6zYdwJy299N7lcXcA==/lib/arm64/liblgpllibs.so: unhandled flags #8 not handled
2019-11-08 12:50:30.921 14939-14939/com.geckoengine.example D/GeckoNetworkManager: Incoming event enableNotifications for state OnNoListeners -> OnWithListeners
2019-11-08 12:50:30.922 14939-14939/com.geckoengine.example D/GeckoNetworkManager: New network state: UP, WIFI, WIFI
2019-11-08 12:50:30.923 14939-14939/com.geckoengine.example D/GeckoNetworkManager: Incoming event receivedUpdate for state OnWithListeners -> OnWithListeners
2019-11-08 12:50:30.924 14939-14939/com.geckoengine.example D/GeckoNetworkManager: New network state: UP, WIFI, WIFI
2019-11-08 12:50:30.928 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example D/GeckoViewTelemetryController: observed internal-telemetry-geckoview-load-complete - ready to handle telemetry requests
2019-11-08 12:50:30.938 14939-15019/com.geckoengine.example I/GeckoConsole: OpenGL compositor Initialized Succesfully.
    Version: OpenGL ES 3.2 V@385.0 (GIT@bc00834, I609ab310b2) (Date:04/11/19)
    Vendor: Qualcomm
    Renderer: Adreno (TM) 540
    FBO Texture Target: TEXTURE_2D
2019-11-08 12:50:30.943 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example W/GeckoLinker: /data/app/com.geckoengine.example-790VO6zYdwJy299N7lcXcA==/lib/arm64/libsoftokn3.so: unhandled flags #8 not handled
2019-11-08 12:50:30.944 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example W/GeckoLinker: /data/app/com.geckoengine.example-790VO6zYdwJy299N7lcXcA==/lib/arm64/libfreebl3.so: unhandled flags #8 not handled
2019-11-08 12:50:30.956 14939-15013/com.geckoengine.example W/GeckoLinker: /data/app/com.geckoengine.example-790VO6zYdwJy299N7lcXcA==/lib/arm64/libnssckbi.so: unhandled flags #8 not handled
2019-11-08 12:50:31.109 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example W/oengine.exampl: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Boolean;->value:Z (greylist-max-p, JNI, denied)
2019-11-08 12:50:31.109 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example W/oengine.exampl: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Integer;->value:I (greylist-max-p, JNI, denied)
2019-11-08 12:50:31.109 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example W/oengine.exampl: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Double;->value:D (greylist-max-p, JNI, denied)
2019-11-08 12:50:31.132 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example I/Gecko: [Parent 14939, Main Thread] WARNING: failed to open shm: Permission denied: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/base/shared_memory_posix.cc, line 106
2019-11-08 12:50:31.127 14939-14939/com.geckoengine.example W/Gecko: type=1400 audit(0.0:7680): avc: denied { open } for path="/dev/ashmem" dev="tmpfs" ino=16646 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c90,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:ashmem_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
2019-11-08 12:50:31.136 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example I/Gecko: [Parent 14939, Main Thread] WARNING: failed to open shm: Permission denied: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/base/shared_memory_posix.cc, line 106
2019-11-08 12:50:31.130 14939-14939/com.geckoengine.example W/Gecko: type=1400 audit(0.0:7681): avc: denied { open } for path="/dev/ashmem" dev="tmpfs" ino=16646 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c90,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:ashmem_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
2019-11-08 12:50:31.136 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example E/GeckoConsole: [JavaScript Error: "NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIScriptSecurityManager.getLoadContextContentPrincipal]" {file: "chrome://global/content/elements/browser-custom-element.js" line: 1231}]
    construct@chrome://global/content/elements/browser-custom-element.js:1231:38
    connectedCallback@chrome://global/content/elements/browser-custom-element.js:381:12
    init@chrome://geckoview/content/geckoview.js:69:37
    startup@chrome://geckoview/content/geckoview.js:449:17
2019-11-08 12:50:31.137 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example E/GeckoConsole: [JavaScript Error: "TypeError: this.messageManager is null" {file: "chrome://geckoview/content/geckoview.js" line: 77}]
    init@chrome://geckoview/content/geckoview.js:77:5
    startup@chrome://geckoview/content/geckoview.js:449:17
2019-11-08 12:50:31.138 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example D/GeckoThread: State changed to RUNNING
2019-11-08 12:50:31.138 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example I/GeckoSession: zerdatime 307605471 - chrome startup finished
2019-11-08 12:50:31.143 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example D/GeckoViewStartup: onEvent GeckoView:SetLocale
2019-11-08 12:50:31.144 14939-15019/com.geckoengine.example E/Gecko: ShmemAndroid::Create():open: Permission denied (13)
2019-11-08 12:50:31.144 14939-15019/com.geckoengine.example E/Gecko: ShmemAndroid::Map(): Bad file descriptor (9)
2019-11-08 12:50:31.145 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example D/GeckoViewStartup: onEvent GeckoView:ResetUserPrefs
2019-11-08 12:50:31.140 14939-14939/com.geckoengine.example W/Thread-3: type=1400 audit(0.0:7682): avc: denied { open } for path="/dev/ashmem" dev="tmpfs" ino=16646 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c90,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:ashmem_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
2019-11-08 12:50:31.160 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example D/GeckoViewXUL: onEvent GeckoView:UpdateModuleState {"enabled":true,"module":"GeckoViewSelectionAction"}
2019-11-08 12:50:31.161 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example E/GeckoConsole: [JavaScript Error: "TypeError: this._manager.messageManager is null" {file: "chrome://geckoview/content/geckoview.js" line: 358}]
    _loadFrameScript@chrome://geckoview/content/geckoview.js:358:5
    set enabled@chrome://geckoview/content/geckoview.js:391:12
    onEvent@chrome://geckoview/content/geckoview.js:218:11
2019-11-08 12:50:31.217 14939-14982/com.geckoengine.example E/GeckoConsole: [JavaScript Error: "undefined"]
```

All other sample GeckoView projects from Github didn't work either, same error.
Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you post it here instead of submitting a bug repot to the project?

Comment: @Zaffy because I am not sure if it's a GeckoView error or just my fault

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in GeckoView, can you open one at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GeckoView&component=General